# R: for loop through n columns of a data frame each time

Tags: r, for-loop

Need help in solving this problem. I have below data frame, where **Grp** is my id column and columns **A** through **I** are my numeric variables. The number of numeric columns in my data frame can vary. It can go from 5 to 500 or even more.

```
data <- data.frame("Grp" = rep(c("GRP_A1", "GRP_A2", "GRP_A3", "GRP_A4", "GRP_A5"), each = 5),
  A = rep(1:5, each = 5), 
  B = rep(6:10, each = 5), 
  C = rep(11:15, each = 5), 
  D = rep(16:20, each = 5),
  E = rep(21:25, each = 5), 
  G = rep(26:30, each = 5), 
  H = rep(31:35, each = 5),
I = rep(36:40, each = 5))

> head(data)
     Grp A B  C  D  E  G  H  I  J  K
1 GRP_A1 1 6 11 16 21 26 31 36 41 51
2 GRP_A1 1 6 11 16 21 26 31 36 41 51
3 GRP_A1 1 6 11 16 21 26 31 36 41 51
4 GRP_A1 1 6 11 16 21 26 31 36 41 51
5 GRP_A1 1 6 11 16 21 26 31 36 41 51
6 GRP_A2 2 7 12 17 22 27 32 37 42 52
```

And I have a condition, lets say **n**

```
n <- 3
```

What I am looking for is

1. Run a for loop with some calculations on **n** consecutive columns after subsetting along with my id column **Grp.**
   Select ID & n columns in each loop, run a calculation
2. Save each of the newly created df as csv file.

Currently  this is how I am doing it, which is not sustainable.

**Any help is much appreciated**

```
n <- 3

df1 <- data %>%
  select(1, 2:4) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = 2:4, names_to = "Trait", values_to = "Value")
write.csv(df1, "DF1.csv", row.names = F)

df2 <- data %>%
  select(1, 5:7) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = 2:4, names_to = "Trait", values_to = "Value")
write.csv(df2, "DF2.csv", row.names = F)

df3 <- data %>%
  select(1, 8:9) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = 2:3, names_to = "Trait", values_to = "Value")
write.csv(df3, "DF3.csv", row.names = F)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
i <- 1
n <- 3
startCol <- 2
endCol <- startCol + n - 1
stopNow <- FALSE
while(!stopNow) {
  if (endCol == data %>%  ncol())  stopNow <- TRUE
  tmp <- data %>% 
           select(all_of(c(1, startCol:endCol))) %>% 
           pivot_longer(
             cols = startCol:endCol, 
             names_to = "Trait", 
             values_to = "Value"
           )
  write.csv(tmp, file.path(paste0("DF", i), ".csv"), row.names = F)
  startCol <- endCol + 1
  endCol <- startCol + n - 1
  if (endCol > data %>% ncol()) endCol <- data %>% ncol()
  i <- i + 1
}
```

Though I'd hope there was some structure in your column names that would make this easier.